# Не переведена строка в подсказке по горячим клавишам

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Не переведена строка `switch to question list` на вкладке вопросы:

[image: Горячие клавиши:]

---

**P.S.:** Хорошо бы ещё поправить стиль записи остальных слов. `Мета` и `Неотвеченные` почему-то написаны с прописной буквы, а у `вопросов` неправильное склонение:

[image: перейти...]

Comment: Поправил [неотвеченные](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/9419) и [мета](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/1554). Может в другом месте сломается :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложил перевод `переключиться на список вопросов` [утверждён]:

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11368

Comment: Утвердил. Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.8.27.40079